# C++ OpenCV imshow memory leak

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, imshow

I have a simple problem however I'm not sure how it could be solved. I have the following code (c++):

```
Mat myImage;
for(;;){
    imshow("Name", myImage);
}
```

Lets make the assumption that `myImage` is already populated with an image here. For some reason this very simple code is causing a memory leak. I read somewhere online that supplying imshow with the same image results in imshow adding it as a seperate axis, increase the memory comsumption.

Basically I dont know how to stop this memory leak. Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

Here is a screen shot of what I'm seeing when analysing memory usage.
[image]

**Edit 2**

Here is an example xcode project, made from scratch to display this issue. If you cannot run xcode, I've also provided a copy of the code on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=XyiGaA4v). The project files can be downloaded from [here](http://jmp.sh/XUipJgn).

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Can't you just `Mat myImage; // populate myImage; imshow("Name", myImage), waitKey();`?

Comment: Yes (from the code above) I could. However this code was setup as a test. The actual code takes images from a camera (which is where the loop comes in). However there was a memory leak, so to try and find the source I started testing. This code is the smallest amount necessary to produce the leak.

Comment: Actually it doesn't leak for me. Your opencv version?

Comment: Oh really? I installed using Homebrew with the --HEAD flag, so it should be the latest version of master? Out of interest, which version and OS are you using?

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only person having a problem though. Apparently its possibly a QT leak within OpenCV? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13777473/1183362

Comment: No leaks with OpenCV 2.4.9 and OpenCV 3.0, Visual Studio 2013, Win 8.1. Note that the last link refers to OpenCV 2.3.1, so it's quite old. Probably is something related to Qt, and not OpenCV

Comment: Hmmm yes I'm thinking QT issue too. I'm using latest branch of master but on OSX 10.11.1. Thinking its something to do with creating a window on a mac, which does not exist within Windows?

Comment: Ok, analyzing leaks I got exactly the same as in the question you linked, but the memory occupancy doesn't increase. The detected leak is just 138 bytes. So it is a false positive?

Comment: And this is a [know bug](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4386) (at least on Windows), i.e. a **one time** memory leak when calling `imshow`. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: This is more than a one time leak. When running the above code with my setup, I see a significant rise in memory usage. I've attached the results of my analysis to the question so you can see what I'm seeing. This was after only 2 mins of streaming video. Are you both running your tests on Windows? If so, could it be a Mac thing?

Comment: please post also a [mcve] that I can copy and run

Comment: Sure the question has been modified to display this information now.

Comment: I'm having to go out now, so all my future replies will be tomorrow. Thanks for all of the help so far!

Comment: Works perfectly for me... Good luck with this one!

Comment: No leaks here: OpenCV 2.4.10 and OpenCV 3.0, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks for all the testing! Can anyone confirm if they have tested on OSX?